# With and without a seemingly unnecessary pointer declaration in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have this piece of code, where I calculate the sum of an array of integers using pointers:

```
int exercise1c (void){

int arr[] = {12, 7, -3, 4, 1};
int *numb = arr; 
int i;
int sum;

while (i<5){
  sum += *(arr + i);
  i++;
}

printf("%d", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

However, I noticed that the line int `*numb = arr;` isnt really used anywhere. So I tried deleting it, which results in a very weird, random number (like 15775252). Can anyone explain to me why is deleting that line causing this problem??

Comment: Initialize `sum` ... `int sum = 0;`, and beware overflow

Comment: BTW: `sum += *(arr + i);` can also be written as `sum += arr[i];`

Comment: ... and in my opinion should *only ever be written as `arr[i]`*...

Comment: General rule: If removing untelated code changes the behaviour of your program, that is a strong indication that your program invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Local variables need to be initialized before they are used. Turn up the compiler warnings (using options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` with gcc or clang) and the compiler will remind you about this. In your code, you need to initialize `sum` and `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized non-statlic local variable `int sum;`, which is indeterminate.

Then, it seems deleting the line affected the optimization process of your compiler in some way.

Initialize the variable (for example, `int sum = 0;`) to avoid the problem.